# Geocortex creating duplicate columns on Replica Datasets

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, replication, geocortex, amazon-web-services

I have a Geocortex site that utilises data located on an Amazon Workspace. The data originates from a local SQL server and is replicated to the Workspace when the data is updated.

Each time this replication occurs, duplicate columns appear in Geocortex.

Has anyone else come across this? Can anyone offer a solution?

Comment: Which columns are duplicated?  If the data replication changes the data store then the OBJECTID, SHAPE, SHAPE.LEN/SHAPE.AREA fields may get added again by the new geodatabase.